# Error Getting HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host in Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I Working in asp.net web api

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Domain()
{
     Fun(); // <- without thread
     Task.Run(() => Fun()); // <- with thread
     return Ok();
}

public void Fun()
{
     string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;           
}
```

When I call Fun() **without thread**, no errors occur!
**But** whenI call Fun **with thread** An error occurs for this line:

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

Error Message:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   MyProject.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The http context is only accessible on the main request thread.

Comment: Your threadpool threads have no idea about the current `HttpContext`, only the thread that served the request does.

Comment: Why dont you pass the url to the method? You could pass the whole context, but that could lead to problems. The execution context of the task that you are starting wont contain that value even if it is eventually executed on the same thread. The context is destroyed when the action terminates and the controller is disposed. You certainly can leave background task behind from the action as long as you pass anything it needs to work with and you dont want to change the response in any way as there is no such thinh at that time. Likewise there is no request either.